# How to use the scaffolded LoginModel in another view than Login.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I created a dropdown menu to log in instead of logging in at Login.cshtml but i can't seem to be able to use the model that contains the email password etc. I am not sure how to explain this but here is what i made so far:

I created the dropdown form and placed it in _LoginPartial.cshtml so it shows on the navbar

```
       <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Log-In
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="width: 300px" >


                   <!----------->

     <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h3><b>Log In</b></h3></div>
              <form id="ajax-login-form" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-danger" value="Log In">
                    </div>
                </div>


                 <div class="col-xs-5" align="Center">
                      <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" name="remember" id="remember">
                      <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                    </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <a  tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

and after this, i thought i can easily just insert `@model loginmodel` and i can start using that model but i'm met with so many errors. Any advice on how to do this? I am also open to other approaches too

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad and lacks any specificity on "errors" - you're asking for guesses from this community. You've posted a standard `html` form (doesn't even have an `action` btw), which at the end of the day, you _can_ use, but requires more effort than doing it the more standard "ASP.Net MVC way".  Suggestion: Look over the scaffold `Login.cshtml` file that is generated by Visual Studio as that is the best place to start and contains all the info needed.

Comment: Could you post the errors you get?